# What's the PHP equivalent of Pascal's Move when the source is an integer and the destination is a string?

Tags: php, delphi, pascal

I am converting some Pascal to PHP. Inside a function of return type `AnsiString` there are the following lines of code:

```
SetLength(Result, 3);
Move(I, Result[1], Length(Result));
```

`I` is a `Longint` with value 5051253. What ends up in `Result` is `'u'#19'M'`.

How do I replicate that in PHP? What is it doing? I know `Move` reads bytes from `I` and puts them in `Result`.

Comment: `$Result = array(null, null, null); $Result[1] = $I;`? Not sure what you're trying to do. Can you explain us better?

Comment: the problem is I don't know what the Move function in pascal is really doing. I think it has to do with ansistring being a string and I being a longint.

Comment: [Here's documentation](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/move.html). I hope it will help you.

Comment: There is one question "what this Pascal/Delphi code is doing" on low ASM level. There is another question "how to replicate this low-level ASM functioning in PHP. And those are different questions in different domains. Voted for close.

Comment: This question is endianess dependent.

Comment: An other vote to close: this question has 4 close votes for 4 different reasons. I voted for "too localized": This question is probably on topic and answerable, but the idea of copying byte values from an Integer straight into a string is so wrong, no one will probably ever do this again. And if no one does this again then this question is Too Localized, sorry. @AriKooshesh, you should probably FIX that Delphi code, not translate it to a different programming language.

Comment: @CosminPrund that's not a valid reason to close, the question is valid & interesting and not closing it might ensure no one else does it. :)

Comment: However I do agree with your sentiment, and I would like to know why you would convert pascal to php!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function low3bytes( $I) {
  return chr(         $I           % 256)
       . chr( ((int) ($I /   256)) % 256)
       . chr( ((int) ($I / 65536)) % 256);
}
```

**Caveat:** Not tested.

Answer (score 3):

The first line sets the length of variable "Result" to 3 bytes.

I don't know where the value of I comes from, but it is pointing to another variable in memory probably.

Second line is copying 3 bytes from that pointed memory area into variable "Result".

What you need to do is to look at where that variable "I" points to and build up the PHP code according to that.

Let's say, I refers to another ansistring variable "Source". Then you can do that:

`$Result = substr($Source, 0, 3);'

Comment: I is a longint with value 5051253 . You haven't done anything more than restate my question. Nor was it helpful. Why, when those bytes are copied, does an ansistring have that value? Which bytes are causing that?

Comment: You asked "any clue as to what's it doing". And this is an answer. Your new question is funny, as you could answer it yourself. The length of the string 'result' is set to 3 (there is a length information in a string). And then the first three bytes of that string are filled with whatever the first three bytes of `I` are. Get it?

Comment: Depending on Delphi version (which topicstarter should put in tags but did not do) it could either be potential access violation (memory write outside allocated area)  or garbage in the result

Comment: It's the intended result. It's what I want to see. What I want to know is how to replicate it in php.

Comment: @AriKooshen Depending on Delphi version either 1st two bytes are "u", and the second pair is #19, or the 1st byte is "u", the 2nd one is #19 and the 2rd one is "M"

Comment: Does PHP has dynamic array of byte or some other buffer ? String here is used not as a string variable, but a convenient buffer (actually that is weird, dynamic array pf bytes would work better). So take whatever php type is for raw memory access and fill it.

Comment: PHP has no "type for raw memory access".

Comment: Your interpretation of `I` is wrong. `Move` does not treat the value in `I` as an address. It's treated as a *value*. The address of `I` is implicitly passed to `Move` (as is the address of `Result[1]`) because `Move` takes [*untyped* const and var parameters](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/untyped). Sean's code demonstrates the actual result of the function.